# How to deal with defining the solution of a partially differential equation in terms of itself?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the solution to this partially differential equation:

$u_t + uu_x = 0$

$
u(x,0) = 
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & |x| > 1 \\
      1-x^2 & |x| \geq 1
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$

I have gotten to the point where I have determined that,

$\frac{dx}{dt} = u(t,x)$

$x = ut + x_o$

$x_o  = x-ut$

and...

$\frac{du}{dt} = 0$

$u=c_1$

$u(x_o, 0) = 
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & |x_o| > 1 \\
      1-x_o^2 & |x_o| \geq 1
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

so once you plug back in the value for $x_o$ you get,

$u(x, t) = 
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & |x-ut| > 1 \\
      1-(x-ut)^2 & |x-ut| \geq 1
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

From here I do not know where to go because I have u on both sides of the equation, does anyone know how I should deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions are : $
\begin{cases}
u(x,0)=0 & |x|>1\\
u(x,0)=1-x^2 & |x|\leq 1
\end{cases} $

The solution is : 
$\begin{cases}
u(x,t)=0 & |x-ut|>1\\
u(x,t)=1-(x-ut)^2 & |x-ut|\leq 1
\end{cases} $

In the range where $u(x,t)=1-(x-ut)^2$ 
$$u(x,t)=\frac{2xt-1\pm\sqrt{(2xt-1)^2-4t^2(x^2-1)}}{t^2}$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{2xt-1\pm\sqrt{4t^2-4xt+1}}{t^2}$$
With this formula, for each given value of $t$ one can draw $u(x)$ as shown on the figure below :

[image]

The curves are arcs of parabola.

The case $t=1$ is represented by the vertical line at $x=1$.

the case $t>1$ is represented by the horizontal line $u=0$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial s} = 1$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = u(x,t)$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} = 0$

From the first equation you see that s=t (up to an additive constant).

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}  (x(s),t(s)) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (x(t),t) = u_x (x(t),t) \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + u_t(x(t),t) = u_x u + u_t=0$ Therefore u has to be constant at the characteristic x(t) and therefore $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = u(x(t),t) = const.$

Now you just have to use intial values.

Comment: @Tim Smith: there is probably a typing mistake in your question. It should be : $$\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & |x| > 1 \\
      1-x^2 & |x| \leq 1
    \end{array}
\end{array} \quad\text{ instead of }\quad \begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & |x| > 1 \\
      1-x^2 & |x| \geq 1
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$ A part this, your solution is correct.